# Find frequency response of an accelerometer from the datasheet

Tags: datasheet, accelerometer

I'm looking for an accelerometer with about 1 kHz frequency response (~1 ms response time.)

I found two components which I think might be adequate, but I'm not sure since I can't properly understand their datasheets.

These are the two components:

1. [ADXL345](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/ADXL345.pdf)
2. [ADXL377](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/ADXL377.pdf)

I'd be grateful if anyone could explain to me which field should I look at when reading those datasheets in order to understand the device's response time (or frequency response like [here](https://www.farnell.com/datasheets/2917176.pdf) which was more clear to me.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've picked some very different accelerometers there.

The ADXL345 is a digital accelerometer - it delivers acceleration values over a digital SPI or I2C bus.

The ADXL and the TE 4020 are both analog models - the accelerometer output is an analog value you will have to digitize.

For the ADXL345, you can select the desired data rate via a digital command to the device.

The available data rates (and the corresponding sensor bandwidths) are given in table 7 on page 14 of the datasheet:

[image]

The bandwidth of the ADL377 is determined by the values of the capacitors that you connect between each axis output and ground.

The maximum bandwidth is 1000Hz - even if you don't install a filter capacitor.

From page 9 of the datasheet:

[image]

- The AD345 gives you 1600 Hz or 800 Hz.  You can't get 1000 Hz exactly.
- The AD345 saves you from having three analog to digital converters (if your task requires digital processing.)
- The AD377 gives you at most 1000 Hz.

Comment: thank you very much for the detailed answer. do you know by any chance if there's a need for special module that connects devices which use SPI\I2C bus to Arduino? I saw some guides that connect the ADXL345 to the Arduino without any modules in between, but some other guides did use a specialized module, so I'm a bit confused.

Comment: Arduinos can "speak" SPI and I2C directly.  You may need a level translator, since the ADXL345 is 3.3V only - most Arduinos use 5V logic levels.

Comment: [Adafruit has a library and a breakout board for the ADXL345.](https://learn.adafruit.com/adxl345-digital-accelerometer/overview)  Have a look at their adapter.

Comment: @JRE hi, I want to work with adxl345. I have a question, data rate is 3200 but bandwidth is 1600. Is this because ( A sufficient sample-rate is therefore anything larger than 2B samples per second. Equivalently, for a given sample rate f_{s}, perfect reconstruction is guaranteed possible for a bandlimit  B<f_{s}/2}.) this ?

Comment: @Tryingtogetsome:  Yep.  That's pretty much it.

Comment: @JRE thank you so much. I don't understand this, data rate is 50hz for example, it can send data 0.02 s . does bandwidth has buffer for other values ? because band with is 25 hz and It can may miss other values .

Comment: If you switch the 50Hz sampling (data rate,) it makes a measurement 50 times per second.  It filters out anything faster than 25Hz because any signal faster than 25Hz would not be represented correctly when measured only 50 times per second.